# Need help to rearrange Google Sheets columns during append

Tags: javascript, json, function, google-sheets, append

Rephrasing a previous post for more clarity-

I am importing a JSON API into Sheets and the columns are not always consistently in the same place every time it reloads which is normal for JSON from what I hear. The problem is, when I append the data into another sheet to store it, every other append has the columns all mixed up (column G is now F, etc.). This makes it really hard to dedupe considering the dedupe views the columns in different places as unique.

my question is would any of the below work -

1. Is there a way to have my script (below) to arrange the columns into the same column A:G every time?
2. Is there a way to have the API import the columns into the same place every time even though it is changing from the source?
3. Is there a way to re-arrange/sort column headers after appending the column similar to sorting an entire column but instead just header row.

Below is the script to append to sheet 2 which works fine but showing incase option #1 above is the best choice.

```
function saveData() { 
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
 var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]; 
 var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheets()[1]; 
 var rows = sheet1.getRange("A1:G"+sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues(); sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows); }
```

Comment: The answer of this can't come without seeing the structure of the JSON that you're appending. In theory, yes, you can arrange the data but an example of the data would need to be known.

Comment: Can you clarify ` import the columns into the same place every time even though it is changing from the source?`?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Yes to clarify, I am importing using importJSON() and the source API changes column positions every time it refreshes the import. I don't think you can change everything coming in during the import but what I think may be possible is to assign them a standard order during the append from sheet 1 to sheet 2 seen in my script above. Maybe something like if header = column 1 then sheet2.setValues(example set to column A every time). Then column 2 which may come in as column 3 in the export the next refresh would still be assigned column B in sheet 2 during the append/setvalues

Comment: @RafaGuillermo So the import is not doing anything wrong, it is only placing them in the same order that the API is but the JSON API changes order periodically. Going to the source site, for example clicks is last but then going 1 minute later last_active is the last column. Separate from the import is the code I provided which appends the import on sheet 1 onto sheet 2 for storage purposes. I want sheet 2 to be able to keep the same order even though the imported sheet 1 may be changing often. This way I can dedupe sheet 2 without it recognizing shuffled cols with the same data as same.

Comment: Can you provide a sample JSON that you are imnporting? Also a copy of your sheet? I think this will be easier to understand visually.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I cant provide the JSON because it is protected but the columns imported are "Searches" "Hour" "Id" "Est Revenue" "Last Updated" "Campaign" and "Clicks". Sometimes clicks is in column G during import other times F. I don't believe the answer is going to be in fixing the API import because that can stay in whatever order. I care more about the order that the appended Sheet 2 (based off code above) is showing. If there was a way to fix the above script to say even though the next update may put "clicks" in column B...I still want Sheet 2 to put it in Column G to keep sheet 2 same.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo My guess would be that I need to either 1. assign each column to a var based on the column header name (I don't know how to do this). OR 2. some type of transpose function on sheet 2, then sort A->Z, then transpose back to normal...resulting in the top header row now being in an order. Option 2 would need to make sure all of the rows below it stay in the correct order/placement throughout the transpose/sorting/transpose. I do not know how to do either of these but hoping somebody better at this would.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I changed the link in sheet 1 to a placeholder so I can share but you can still see the data on sheet 2 that will be what the output would look like. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PRm8wtKHPKKffz4Y4-JQdtlcydavkA_D8qHdY0I7r_8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using option 3 not using script by including the below formula into the worksheet.

=transpose(sort(transpose(A1:G),1,))

I would have liked to do this all via script but this works too.